# Getting a filtered dictionary of TreeNodes and Collection with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, treeview

I would like to filter a list which is the value of a dictionary and return a filtered dictionary. For example like in this ListView:

```
var filteredLvItems = ConfigManager.TemplateNamesAsLvItem
                .Where(x => x.Text.ToUpper()
                .StartsWith(searchParam))
                .ToArray();
```

ConfigManager is a static class and TemplateNamesAsLvItem a static property. searchParam is the content of a TextBox where the user can filter the values.
Now I have this datatype:

```
 Dictionary<TreeNode, TreeNodeCollection>
```

where the key is the parent node and the value are the childnodes. I tried this to achieve a dictionary with all the filtered TreeNodeCollection nodes:

```
  var filteredTvCollection = ConfigManager.TemplateNamesAsNodes.Values
                .Cast<TreeNode>()
                .Where(y => y.Text.StartsWith(searchParam))
                .ToDictionary(t => t, t => t.Nodes);

            treeViewTemplates.Nodes.Clear();

            foreach (KeyValuePair<TreeNode, TreeNodeCollection> nodes in filteredTvCollection)
            {
                if (!treeViewTemplates.Nodes.Contains(nodes.Key))
                    treeViewTemplates.Nodes.Add(nodes.Key);

                var indexOfParentNode = GetParentNodeIndexByNodeName(nodes.Key.Text);

                if (nodes.Value.Count > 0)
                    treeViewTemplates.Nodes[indexOfParentNode].Nodes.AddRange(nodes.Value.Cast<TreeNode>().ToArray());
```

The aim is to filter this list, clear the treeview and show only the "filtered" treeview to the user.
I know this code does not work but everything else caused errors. This one crashes.
Is this issue possible? I'm trying to avoid foreach loops and unnesessary code. Hope somebody can help me! 
Thank you!

EDIT:

I also tried this:

```
 foreach (KeyValuePair<TreeNode, TreeNodeCollection> nodes in ConfigManager.TemplateNamesAsNodes)
            {
                if (!treeViewTemplates.Nodes.Contains(nodes.Key))
                    treeViewTemplates.Nodes.Add(nodes.Key);

                var indexOfParentNode = GetParentNodeIndexByNodeName(nodes.Key.Text);

                if (nodes.Value != null)
                    treeViewTemplates.Nodes[indexOfParentNode].Nodes
                        .AddRange(nodes.Value.Cast<TreeNode>()
                        .Where(t => t.Text.Contains(searchParam)).ToArray());
            }
```

but nothing happens there. Just the parent nodes are getting imported.

Comment: I feel like you haven't attempted to debug this on your own yet. I only say that because you mentioned "This one crashes" without specifying why or how. if you debug it, find where it crashes and take a look around your debugger. Apart from that, we would just be debugging your code for you.

Comment: I debugged this and I know why this crashes. This is not the point. This was the early code I had. I don't want to post here every variation I tried. I don't know how to achieve this case and if this works with linq. This was the closest code which worked. Because this I'm asking here. Don't understand me wrong please!

Comment: *This one crashes*, *it tells me* - Please give exact exception messages.

Comment: It tells me that the type TreeNode can not be converted to the given dictionary.

Comment: *Exact* error messages: = type  of exception + the message as the exception states it. + the line where it occurs.

Comment: Ok I edited my second code. I think this is the closest now. The parent nodes are getting imported but no childnodes. Where is the problem? The Linq statement looks ok.